# Non-repudiation and digital signature of a dishonest participant

Tags: signature, algorithm-design, protocol-design, non-repudiation

Let's assume a dishonest Alice who sends, encrypts & digitally signs a message to Bob.

Bob stores the decrypted message and the digital signature in a database.

However, Alice is a bad girl and erases all data from her side, including her private/public keys. She then claims she never sent the message.

Is there a solution to this case?

In my case, Alice uses a communication tool that Bob has provided, where the private/public keys are generated within the context of the tool (with no 'public key' advertised anywhere else, hence making it even more difficult to prove anything).

Comment: Who's the dishonest third party? Alice isn't a third party; she's a normal party to the communication, whereas a third party is someone who's *not* supposed to be directly involved with the communication.

Comment: correct - I have changed the title

Comment: You need a certification authority to certify the public key. From a practical sense you can used existing blockchain techs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the solution is that her public key needs to be stored in a place that is and will be accessible to Bob.

(such as in Bob's database)

I had not realized that importance of that before reading your question.

Comment: however, if Alice dishonestly deletes her public key from her device, she can always claim that whatever public key is stored on the server was not hers :(

Comment: Yes. $\:$ That issue is also fundamental for nonrepudiation, but it's independent $\hspace{1.75 in}$ of the issue raised in your opening post. $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: So how can I solve this aspect of nonrepudiation?

Comment: The most generic way is a (physically) signed contract stating that, in return for something, Alice will be bound to a certain extent by signed messages that are compatible with [specific public key]. $\:$ One potential alternative is a (video-and-audio) recording of Alice stating that she will be bound to a certain extent by signed messages that are compatible with [specific public key]. $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: Ok - I am not sure yet about my math there, but does that also applies to any ephemeral key form a ECDHE? (the long public key binding therefore any ephemeral key?)

Comment: ... key agreement usually doesn't need nonrepudiation. $\;$

Comment: (My initial comment shouldn't have said "also". $\:$ The issue raised in your OP is $\hspace{1.5 in}$ hardly "fundamental", it's just an important subtlety.) $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: Thanks Ricky for the quality of your help on this subject!

Comment: Regardless of which way you go, you may wish to look at the [relevant parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signatures_and_law#United_States) for both Alice's and Bob's laws, and explicitly reference them in the contract or what Alice says, as the case may be. $\hspace{.96 in}$

Comment: Ultimately, nonrepudiation is legal and not technological. Bob could then point to evidence that they negotiated, evidence Alice was benefitting from him following his side, etc. - his argument need not be technological.